# Waypoints with coordinates in R

Tags: r, point, coordinates, line

I have a `SpatialLineDataFrame` with 20 observations of 4 variables (in WGS84). I want to create waypoints every 10 meters. Every waypoint will has the x y coordinates. I tried to do it manually like:

```
point_first=SpatialPoints(cbind(x,y))
```

for the first point, but there are many points I want to do, so it is not possible to do it that way. I think I need a loop but I don't know how to do it in order to have the coordinates for every waypoint.

Is there any command that I should use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a nice tutorial on segmentation of spatial lines which you can find [here](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/10685_1f7266d60db7432486517a111c76ac8b.html), and you could make use of `CreateSegment` to achieve your goal. But first of all, let's create some sample data.

```
## german borders
library(rgdal)
library(rworldmap)

data(countriesCoarse)
spy_germany <- subset(countriesCoarse, GEOUNIT == "Germany")

## polygons to lines
sln_germany <- as(spy_germany, "SpatialLinesDataFrame")
```

Since you'd like to work with meters rather than degrees, reproject the data (e.g. to UTM) and extract the coordinates which we will require later on as input for `CreateSegment`.

```
## reprojection (utm-32n) and extraction of coordinates
sln_germany_utm <- spTransform(sln_germany, CRS("+init=epsg:32632"))
mat_germany_crd <- coordinates(sln_germany_utm)[[1]][[1]]
```

Next, let's create a sequence representing the desired segmentation. `rgeos::gLength` comes in quite handy for that. I chose segments of 100 km in length.

```
## border length and sequence of segments (100,000 m = 100 km)
library(rgeos)
num_len <- gLength(sln_germany_utm)

int_len_seq <- seq(0, num_len, 100000)
```

You can now loop over this sequence and extract the start and end coordinate of each single segment.

```
## loop over segments of 100 km
source("CreateSegment.R")

ls_crd_seg <- lapply(2:length(int_len_seq), function(i) {

  # extract coordinates of current line segment
  mat_segment <- CreateSegment(mat_germany_crd, 
                               from = int_len_seq[i-1], to = int_len_seq[i])

  # end coordinate
  crd_out <- matrix(mat_segment[nrow(mat_segment), ], ncol = 2)

  # during the first iteration, also return the start coordinate
  if (i == 2) {
    crd_start <- matrix(mat_segment[1, ], ncol = 2)
    crd_out <- rbind(crd_start, crd_out)
  } 

  return(crd_out)
})
```

Finally, `rbind` the coordinates and assign the projection of our initial shapefile. That's it!

```
## coordinates to SpatialPoints
crd_seg <- do.call("rbind", ls_crd_seg)
spt_seg <- SpatialPoints(crd_seg)
proj4string(spt_seg) <- proj4string(sln_germany_utm)

## visualize
plot(sln_germany_utm, lwd = 1.5)
points(spt_seg)
```

[image: segmented_borders]

Comment: This is a clever approach!

Comment: Very nice approach!

Answer (score 6):

This function will create a systematic point sample of a SpatialLinesDataFrame. The LID column in the results corresponds to the row.names of the source line object and can be used to relate the points to the lines.

```
   # Function for creating a systematic point sample of a SpatialLinesDataFrame
   #   x        SpatialLinesDataFrame
   #   sdist    Distance of sample spacing 
   #   offset   offset for start of line
   #   longlat  TRUE/FALSE, is data in geographic units. If TRUE distance is 
   #              great circle with units (sdist argument) in kilometers.    
    systematic.lineSample <- function(x, sdist=100, offset = 0.5, longlat = FALSE)
       {
        if (!require(sp)) stop("sp PACKAGE MISSING")
         if (!inherits(x, "SpatialLinesDataFrame")) stop("MUST BE SP SpatialLinesDataFrame OBJECT")
        lids <- rownames(x@data)    
        lsub <- x[rownames(x@data) == lids[1] ,]
         LLength <- SpatialLinesLengths(lsub, longlat = longlat)
          ns <- round( (LLength[1] / sdist), digits=0)
          lsamp <- spsample(lsub, n=ns, type="regular", offset=c(offset, offset))
          results <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(lsamp, data=data.frame(LID=rep(as.numeric(lids[1]), ns))) 
        if( length(lids) > 1) { 
          for (i in 2:length(lids) ) 
            {    
             lsub <- x[rownames(x@data) == lids[i] ,]
              LLength <- SpatialLinesLengths(lsub, longlat = longlat)
               ns <- round( (LLength[1] / sdist), digits=0)
               lsamp <- spsample(lsub, n=ns, type="regular")
             lsamp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(lsamp, data=data.frame(LID=rep(as.numeric(lids[i]), ns)))
             results <- rbind(results, lsamp)     
           }
        }
      ( results )
    }
```

Here is an example of the functions usage

```
# Create example data
require(sp)
sp.lines <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(cbind(c(1,2,3),c(3,2,2)))), ID="1"),
                         Lines(list(Line(cbind(c(1,2,3),c(1,1.5,1)))), ID="2")))
sp.lines <- SpatialLinesDataFrame( sp.lines, data.frame(ID=1:2, row.names=c(1,2)) )

# Systematic line sample
lsample <- systematic.lineSample(sp.lines, sdist = 20, offset = 0, longlat = TRUE) 

# Plot results
plot(sp.lines)
  plot(lsample, pch = 20, add = TRUE)
```

Comment: I haven't heard of `sp::SpatialLinesLengths` before, thanks for that! Always better to rely on less packages... anyway, when I tried `systematic.lineSample(sln_germany_utm, sdist = 100000)`, an error was thrown during the `for` loop since only one row name was found (i.e. the initial polygon record). Any way to fix this?

Comment: @fdetsch Done, all the code needed was an if statement proceeding to the loop if there is more than one line. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Note; I also added a longlat argument to indicate geographic units. If the data is in geographic units (longlat=TRUE) then the distance units are in kilometers.

Answer (score 2):

The SpatStat package has a function for creating points along lines at specified intervals.

```
# maptools to read shapefile
require(maptools)
require(spatstat)

# Load a line shapefile
myLine <- readShapeLines("~/workspace/TEMP/myLine.shp")
plot(myLine)
```

[image]

```
# create a PSP object to use with spatstat
myPSP <- as.psp(myLine)

# Create points at 10 km intervals
myPoints <- pointsOnLines(myPSP, 10000)
plot(myPoints, add = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the point placement using `pointsOnLines` is realized for each segment separately (see documentation) instead of considering the line as a whole. Applying your code to my example (with `eps = 100000`) results in a [far too narrow point placing](http://imgur.com/KcNdAIb), e.g. seen from the small jags along the eastern and southern border.

Comment: Aha, had never used this on a multi-segment line (only transects).